# Django reverse lookup on multilevel models

Tags: python, django, relationship

I am trying to query for storetypes at a location without success. I can however query for locations
in a city using the models shown.I want to use the querysets in a menu with a submenu with another
submenu at the root url of the project. Please help.

```
#models

class Supplier():
    shopping_center = models.ForeignKey('Shopping_center')
    storetype = models.ForeignKey('Storetype')



class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()



class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey('City')


    
    
class Shopping_Center(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey('Location')



class Storetype(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
objs = Supplier.objects.select_related('storetype ', 'shopping_center__location__city__name', ).filter(shopping_center__location__city__name__in=['some city'])
```

filter the above an loop through the objs to get storetype

Comment: 'some city' suggests hardcoding which is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: You can pass whatever you like. It's an example.

Comment: I do realise I can do that but it is not the solution I am seeking. I can do city.location_set.all() but cannot do location.storetype_set.all() to only display a storetype in a submenu in a template if the storetype is available at that location.